# Using Django Navbar to create multilevel navigation?

Tags: django, navbar

I'm using Django Navbar http://code.google.com/p/django-navbar/ in the [Mingus blog](http://github.com/montylounge/django-mingus) engine,, I realized that Multi level menus are not implemented (on Mingus) they appear to be implemented in Django navbar.. Have been trying to do it but not joy so far.. I have gotten the breadcrumbs in.. but when I go to a sub page the subpage menu item (in "navbar-two") gets stuck on the left front of the other nav items... what I really want to do is have an "accordion" type drop down menu/nav which I believe can be done via css (assuming I get nav-bar to cough up the right data)?

I have been over the example in the nav-bar code over and over..unfortunately there is no doc... but the example appears to work.. but I can't seem to transfer the code.

I am not seeing the sub bars (navbar-two or three) show up on the page in any form...

I have added the NAVBAR_SHOW_DEPTH = 3 to settings.py (which seems like the main thing to do.

I have limited expertise in the css required and none if it needs JS.. but that is why I'm wanting to learn it.. Can anyone give me a pointer or three ( or more?)